# closing BufferedReader results in Stream closed in Junit

Tags: java, junit

I have several JUnit tests, all of them are invoking the same class (with different inputs), and check for the return value of this class.

The class itself has a code that uses `BufferedReader`, that is being closed at the end of the read. 
The first test is passing, but every test after it is throwing the `Stream closed`

I am creating a new instance of the class in each test, as well as a new `BufferReader` in the read code.

Aren't tests supposed to be contained? isn't a new instance should resolve this issue?

My Example Tests (omitted code that generates different args in each test for readability)

```
public void test1()  {
    float result = 0;
    MyClass myClassInst = new MyClass();

    result = myClassInst.Execute(args);
    assert (result > 0.5);
}

public void test2()  {
    float result = 0;
    MyClass myClassInst = new MyClass();

    result = myClassInst.Execute(args);
    assert (result > 0.5);
}
```

Within myClass I have the following code (INPUT_STREAM is a txt file in my project resources and is identical for every test)

```
ReadInputsClass re = new ReadInputsClass(INPUT_STREAM);
which invokes the following method
```

___EDIT_________

The way I am getting INPUT_STREAM is:
at the top of MyClass I have

```
private static InputStream INPUT_STREAM= initializeInputStream();

private static InputStream initializeInputStream() { InputStream inputStream = System.class.getResourceAsStream("textFile.txt"); return inputStream; }
```

___END EDIT_____

the `ReadInputsClass`  constructor is calling the following code

```
private ArrayList<SomeClass> readStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    ArrayList<SomeClass> ret = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            // do some stuff on the line just read
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Clearly the issue is coming from the `br.close` in this code

when I put a break point, the 2nd test is getting to br that is set to null, creating a new br, and when it is reaching the br.readLine() it is throwing the stream close.

I do not understand why? Isn't the new br = new BufferedReader should start fresh?

Comment: you need to reopen INPUT_STREAM in every test - probably this InputStream is a singleton and is getting closed by the first `BufferedReader`

Comment: isn't this part of the code does that new InputStreamReader(inputStream)?

Comment: no it isn't: this only creates a new wrapper around the same `inputStream` instance

Comment: also this is the way I pass my input stream 
`private static InputStream initializeInputStream() {
        InputStream inputStream = System.class.getResourceAsStream("textFile.txt");

        return inputStream;
    }`

Comment: And where do you call that `initializeInputStream()` method?

Comment: how do you pass it to `ReadInputsClass`?: if `INPUT_STREAM` is a stored variable, drop it and use `new ReadInputsClass(initializeInputStream())` instead

Comment: Also: [Use try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nesting streams in your code:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

In Java, if you close the outer most stream, all other streams in the chain are closed as well. That means if you call br.close(), then the close() method on the InputStreamReader gets called which in turn calls the close method on your inputStream variable.

If you initialize INPUT_STREAM as a static variable and re-use it, that would mean subsequent tests using the INPUT_STREAM variable will use a stream that has already been closed.

Comment: How do you know that INPUT_STREAM is a static variable? Your answer just rephrases the analysis done in the comments by others without definitively knowing if this hypothesis is correct.

Comment: unfortunately the code I am working on is using static all over (code I am maintaining, so removing all those statics is not an option) What would be a good way to recreate INPUT_STREAM?

Comment: I would suggest what @wero mentioned in the comments below your question, that is to create the ReadInputsClass using `new ReadInputsClass(initializeInputStream())` instead of referencing the static INPUT_STREAM variable.